# Ratio of collision of rate between distributions?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, collision, equilibrium

### Background

Consider the familiar setting of statistical mechanics, an assembly of $N=4$ distinguishable gas particles. Let, the total energy be $4E_0$.

The possible ways energy of sharing energy between the particles gives us $5$ possible distributions $D(i)$:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
     & 0 &E_0 & 2E_0 & 3E_0 & 4E_0 \\
D(1) & 3 & 0 & 0 &0  & 1 \\
D(2) & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
D(3) & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
D(4) & 1 & 2 & 1 &0 &0 \\
D(5) & 0 & 4 & 0 &0 & 0 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

The number of microstates in $D(i)$ is given by:

$$ t(D(i)) = \frac{N!}{\prod n_k!}$$

There are $35$ micro-states in total in this example. As,

$$ t(D(1))+ t(D(2)) + t(D(3)) + t(D(4)) + t(D(5)) = 4 +12 + 6+ 12 + 1 =35$$

Since, each microstate is equally probable (at equilibrium) we can take time unit $ 35 \Delta t$ then we can state on average the distributions  are stable for time:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
D(1) & 4  \Delta t \\
D(2) & 12  \Delta t  \\
D(3) & 6  \Delta t  \\
D(4) & 12  \Delta t  \\
D(5) &  \Delta t 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Now, let us only keep track of collisions that change the (energy) distribution. For example, imagine an $D(1) \to D(2)$ where $4E_0 + 0 \to E_0 + E_3$. We restrict ourselves $2$ particles per collision. Then following transitions (between distributions) are only are only allowed.

$$ D(1) \to D(2) , D(3)$$
$$ D(2) \to D(3) , D(1) , D(4)$$
$$ D(3) \to D(1) , D(2) , D(4)$$
$$ D(4) \to D(2) , D(3), D(5) $$
$$ D(5) \to D(4) $$

### Question

Is there nice way to calculate the ratio of collision rate that go from $D(i) \to D(j):D(k) \to D(l) $? Is there generalizable version  for an arbitrary number particles?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779270/ratio-of-collision-of-rate-between-distributions